# how to store data in google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine , I was reading this page : 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

here they have explained how to retrieve data from dataStore:

```
  // Get the Datastore Service
   DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

      // The Query interface assembles a query
Query q = new Query("Person");

   //Use CompositeFilter to set more than one filter
    q.setFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.and(
 new FilterPredicate("lastName", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, lastNameParam),
 new FilterPredicate("height", Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, maxHeightParam)));


    // PreparedQuery contains the methods for fetching query results
   // from the Datastore
    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

  for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
  String firstName = (String) result.getProperty("firstName");
   String lastName = (String) result.getProperty("lastName");
   Long height = (Long) result.getProperty("height");
   System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + height + " inches tall");
  }
```

But how to save this data.where and how this firstName and LastName is Saved in DataStore ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to read some of the other pieces of documentation, such as the one linked just above that one [that explains exactly what to do](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Working_with_Entities)?